# Process for commissioning a new hard-disk-drive with Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have a Lenovo idea-centre pc
The old HDD packed-in.
I bought a new HDD - Seagate Barracuda 4TB
I installed the new HDD today, loaded Ubuntu 22.04 via a live-usb and then rebooted BUT, Ubuntu would not boot - received the message "no operating system found".
I have tried many workarounds - to no avail.
It would appear that there is no boot-loader - ? Grub-2
Can anyone guide me to a solution - I am not very tech-savvy but can use the terminal and carry out monkey-see-monkey-do instructions.
Thank-you for your time
Duncan

Comment: Did you install in UEFI or legacy mode? If you don't wish to troubleshoot, but just fix it, consider using boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks - tried Boot-Repair - did not help

Comment: It's likely your install failed then. Did you get any errors? How about the UEFI vs legacy mode question?

Comment: Here is the reference to the scan Boot-Repair did of my system - it (Boot-Repair) said I should pass this on to any expert who was trying to help me:

Comment: Here is the reference:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bhF83Rx3v5/

Comment: I tried both UEFI and Legacy boots (by changing the options in BIOS)

Comment: There is no bootloader installed at all. Your ESP is formatted with ext4 but must be fat filesystem. I'd suggest ot delete both partitions on the drive and do a clean install ( in UEFI-mode), let the installer create the needed partitions.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and time - I really appreciate it.
I have tried that - sadly does not work - back to square 1.

Comment: Since your reply to all suggestions has been "I already tried that", it would save a lot of wasted time if you put what you already tried in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many, many "solutions" offered by searching the web. I did not write them down as I tried them - it would take pages and pages of text and even then I would miss out some. A recurring theme of the problems is "No EFI" system" Then, when I load and efi-system GParted does not allow me to add a mounting point for the boot. It goes on and on - always, at the end of trying something, "no mount point" or "no EFI system" - If I manage to get both these on then I can't get a mount point for the ext4 Linux partition. Most frustrating - have not slept in days.

Comment: I am taking my machine into the repair shop. Hopefully they will be able to solve the problem.